# How to play input sound immediately (like an echo)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, audio

I'm just starting to learn the Audio SDK for the iPhone/iPad, but my question is simple (hopefully).

Is it possible to 'play' the sound from input immediately?
For example, if you speak into the microphone, can I play it back through the speakers (or headphone) immediately (like a sound monitor) ?

(I'm using xcode 4.2.1, I'd prefer iOS 4.2 as a baseline)

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to get audio feedback problems (squeals) if you make the speaker play the sound directly from the microphone. This is why you can hear your own voice in a telephone earpiece, but not through the speaker when the phone is in speaker mode. You won't have this problem with headphones, though. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback)

Comment: Maybe so, but if that's the case, then why does the speakerphone work?

Comment: Ever notice that you can't have simultaneous conversations with a speakerphone? It's because a speakerphone works in half-duplex mode. When it detects sound from the microphone, it mutes the speaker. In any case, my comment was just to warn you that you may encounter problems when using the speaker. I should have said "You **might** get audio feedback problems".

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly simple. As noted above it will give feedback, but I've worked a lot with audio, and I don't think this will cause you much feedback unless its played very loudly. The microphone and speaker are pointing pretty much the same direction and doesn't pick up a lot on each other I think.

Start here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

If you follow the instructions there and take the input from the inputbuffer and feed it directly into the outputbuffer it should work in theory (I haven't tried it though).

Comment: I briefly looked at this document - it's for OS X. Is it the same for iOS?

Comment: Just a bump here - Is this doc valid for iOS or just OS X ? Thanks.